# Strange results while adding / subtracting Floats in Javascript

Tags: javascript, addition, subtraction

I'm experimenting with JavaScript for the first time. My objective is to build a little 'configurator'. On my page, there are 2 buttons triggering the following functions `onclick`:

```
function default()
{
 curPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById('price').innerHTML);
 newPrice = curPrice-priceEngraving;
 document.getElementById('price').innerHTML=newPrice;
}
```

and the other one looks like this:

```
function engrave()
{
var str = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML;
newPrice = curPrice+priceEngraving;
document.getElementById('price').innerHTML=newPrice;
}
```

`priceEngraving` is defined as 1 and the "default" `innerHtml` of #price is 5.30.
When pressing button 1, the following result comes up:
6.3

This is okay and the expected result (appending a 0 on the end isn't too hard).

When firing button #2 the following result comes up:
5.3000000000000004

I don't know where's the problem in my code. I also tried `++` and `--` (which I don't prefer because, as you know, prices are subject to change).

Also, I know about the security concerns when using JavaScript, but this one's only optical.

Comment: Duplicate question.  Many, many times duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that some numbers can not be representated precisely as a floating point number.
If you always want 2 decimal places then you can use the method `toFixed(2)` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)) on your numbers.

```
document.getElementById('price').innerHTML=newPrice.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having floating point problems.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem) for details, the issues have been covered there in detail.  Basically there is no way to map what you have accurately enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was more accurate, but the other answer has helped me more in finding an acceptable solution!